# django select_related, prefetch_related. How to read django_toolbar?

Tags: django, performance

I have such an outcom form django toolbar. I do not now how can I upgrade my code to get rid of duplicate. How I can decide that I should use `prefetch_related()` or `select_related()`

Why some of lines are few times in a row?

[image: Outcom form django_toolbar]

Comment: I think answer for that is too complex for that site. Basically what you need to do is to check where in code each of queries is triggered, try to re-use previous querysets objects, find out if you can add select related or prefetch related (good place to do this: first 2 queries. I'm pretty sure that you can add `select_related('profile')` to first query, so second won't be needed). It's a lot of work and can't be described in few simple words.

Answer (score 1):

`select_related()` is for foreign keys.

`prefetch_related()` is for M2M.

You will need to add those values that you are displaying in your template.

Also note that if you are displaying values from related model you may need to do something like `select_related('model__fieldname`)`